# Override write function of CakePHP log

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

I'm try **save CakePHP logs in database** (table: logs), but return error when I try:

```
Could not load class Databaselogger
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

Stack Trace
CORE\Cake\Log\LogEngineCollection.php line 42 → LogEngineCollection::_getLogger(string)
CORE\Cake\Log\CakeLog.php line 199 → LogEngineCollection->load(string, array)
APP\Config\bootstrap.php line 31 → CakeLog::config(string, array)
CORE\Cake\Core\Configure.php line 93 → include(string)
CORE\Cake\bootstrap.php line 164 → Configure::bootstrap(boolean)
APP\webroot\index.php line 91 → include(string)
```

---

## DETAILS

**CakePHP:** 2.3
**Apache:** 2.2
**PHP:** 5.3.9
**MySQL:** 5.1

### FILES

**bootstrap.php**

```
CakeLog::config('otherFile', array(
    'engine' => 'Databaselogger'
));
```

**UsersController.php**

```
CakeLog::write('info', $this->alias, null, print_r($this->request->data, true));
```

**app/Log/Databaselogger.php**
*I try in app/Lib/ too, and app/Lib/log too* but doesn't work.

```
<?php
class Databaselogger extends CakeLog {
 
    function __construct() {
        App::import('Model', 'Log');
        $this->Log = new Log;
    }
 
    function write($type, $message, $query, $debug) {
        $this->Log->create();
        
        $log['type'] = ucfirst($type);
        $log['message'] = $message;
        $log['query'] = $query;
        $log['debug'] = $debug;
        $log['created'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $log['modified'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 
        return $this->Log->save($log);
    }
 
}
?>
```

---

**[EDIT]**
I change the location of `DatabaseLogger.php` file, and add 2 important lines:

```
    // app/Lib/Log/Engine/DatabaseLogger.php

    App::uses('CakeLogInterface', 'Log');
    class DatabaseLogger implements CakeLogInterface {
```

And now, "works", but not as I expected, because I need more 2 values in write function: `query, debug`, but isn't allowed. How I do that?

```
    function write($type, $message, $query, $debug) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently do that:

- concatenate all variables and sent in $message param.
- Later, I explode that and use the values

But I think this is wrong.

What I really need is: "custom write function", or: **"how create your custom log"**.

Anyway thanks.